# sub string python pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, substring

I have a pandas dataframe that has a string column in it. The length of the frame is over 2 million rows and looping to extract the elements I need is a poor choice. My current code looks like the following

```
for i in range(len(table["series_id"])):
    table["state_code"] = table["series_id"][i][2:4]
    table["area_code"] = table["series_id"][i][5:9]
    table["supersector_code"] = table["series_id"][i][11:12]
```

where "series_id" is the string containing multiple information fields I want to create an example data element:

columns:

```
 [series_id, year, month, value, footnotes]
```

The data:

```
[['SMS01000000000000001' '2006' 'M01' 1966.5 '']
 ['SMS01000000000000001' '2006' 'M02' 1970.4 '']
 ['SMS01000000000000001' '2006' 'M03' 1976.6 '']
```

However series_id is column of interest that I am struggling with. I have looked at the str.FUNCTION for python and specifically pandas.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern

has a section describing each of the string functions i.e. specifically *get* & *slice* are the functions I would like to use. Ideally I could envision a solution like so:

```
table["state_code"] = table["series_id"].str.get(1:3)
```

or

```
table["state_code"] = table["series_id"].str.slice(1:3)
```

or

```
table["state_code"] = table["series_id"].str.slice([1:3])
```

When I have tried the following functions I get an invalid syntax for the ":".

but alas I cannot seem to figure out the proper way to perform the vector operation for taking a substring on a pandas data frame column.

Thank you

Comment: I think what you want is `table["state_code"] = table["series_id"].str[1:3]`

Comment: Note: that's a really bad way to iterate over the rows, either use iterrows or apply. Using range like that creates a huge python list (in python 2), xrange is slightly better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I would use [str.extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html) with some regex (which you can tweak for your needs):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(["SMU78000009092000001"])

In [12]: s.str.extract('^.{2}(?P<state_code>.{3}).{1}(?P<area_code>\d{4}).{2}(?P<supersector_code>.{2})')
Out[12]: 
  state_code area_code supersector_code
0        U78      0000               92
```

*This reads as: starts (`^`) with any two characters (which are ignored), the next three (any) characters are `state_code`, followed by any character (ignored), followed by four digits are `area_code`, ...*

Comment: Just curious, is the 'Out[12]' returning a Data frame?

Comment: @user3376660 yep, that's a DataFrame, with the group names you're extracting as column names :)

Comment: @user3376660 you'll probably need to tweak the numbers a bit to suit your needs!